# Ionic 2 Google +

Tags: angular, google-oauth, ionic2

Is there any working example for using google + sign in in IONIC2 ? I am kind of new in here. All I see is in Ionic 1.

As far as I see there is these examples on ionic 1:

https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/google-plus-login-with-ionic-framework#step1

github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

And One example with oAuth2 in Ionic2 which is the CLOSEST thing I found in entire world. But to use this example, I am bound to use their "registration" :

http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-and-auth0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use firebase. you can implement google authentification with few lines of code.

```js
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
});
```

please see the doc here [firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html)

Comment: Thank you for the example. I really appreciate it :) But I choose to implement all the things by myself.